# Selenium-Field input values keep on appearing, even after clearing it on both firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I am automating advance search page, where it has many input field values. In first case certain field value is entered then it is cleared in second test case, but again in third case that value was still there even after clearing it second case. Manually this is working fine, value was not there but in automation I have to clear that value in each case thus increasing overhead. I am using **selenium webdriver 2.53** and **firefox 47.0** and keyword driven model.

Delete cookies code is present in the code.If anyone has any idea what is going on, please help.

Comment: Can you paste your code here? Also would be interested in understanding are you navigating between test cases?

Comment: code is plain simple with typing and clear commands. And yes i'm navigating through test cases , with one completed start another. The development have been done through AJs.

Comment: Still trying to understand and hoping you are not doing navigate().back() to land to your search page ?

Comment: No, i am just clicking on button of advance search and doing test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable autofill in firefox profile preference:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.formfill.enable", "false")
```